# putStrLn, type Char does not match [Char]

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io

I have an haskell problem. putStrLn is supposed to take a [Char], or a String, and even though it seems like I give that to mr Compiler, he still complains.

```
*** Expression     : putStrLn line
*** Term           : line
*** Type           : Char
*** Does not match : [Char]
```

The code that it refers to is this:

```
getV::[[(Char,Float)]] -> IO ()
getV [] = putStrLn ""
getV (x:xs) = do line <- getS x
   putStrLn line      <-- Complaining line
   getV xs

getS::[(Char,Float)] -> String
getS [] = ""
getS ((c,f):str) = do a <- "(L" ++ [c] ++")" ++ getS str
    return a
```

I did strip it a little bit, but it should be exactly the same behaviour. getS do return a String and that string is the argument for putStrLn. So what is the problem? :/

Comment: Just a couple bits of formatting advice: your code is badly formatted, and doesn't run in GHC.  Try lining up each line with the line above it (so the `p` of `putStrLn line` is right below the `l` of `line <- getS x`.  Also, it would be nice if you had `-- Complaining line` and left off the `<`, so that it was a legal comment and people could copy-paste your code.

Comment: Yep, you are telling the truth :D I'll be better next time

Comment: Why not be better this time?  You can always go back and edit your question!  (Also, +1 for taking my nitpicks with good humor :)  Good luck with your Haskelling!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your `getS` returns a `String`, not an `IO String`, there's no need to "extract" the pure value with `<-`.

Just use

```
do
  let line = getS x
  putStrLn line
  getV xs
```

---

Also, there's a [`mapM` function](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM) which you can

```
getV xs = mapM (putStrLn.getS) xs
```

and your `getS` is using monads unnecessarily.

```
getS [] = ""
getS ((c,_):str) = "(L" ++ [c] ++ ")" ++ getS str
```

Of course, it's possible to write it using built-in functions only.

```
getS ps = concatMap (\(c,_) -> "(L" ++ [c] ++ ")") ps
```

---

The reason your code doesn't fail on the `line <- getS x` line, and `line` becomes a `Char` is because List is also a monad. For instance, we can write the Cartesian product as

```
cartesian :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
cartesian xs ys = do
    x <- xs    -- # Now x is of type 'a', representing any element in xs
    y <- ys    -- # Now y is of type 'b', representing any element in ys
    return (x, y) -- # Return the tuple composed of any elements in xs and ys.
```

In fact, list comprehension is based on this monadic property of list.

```
cartesian xs ys = [(x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```